# Loading dynamic websites on sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have a couple of HTML files, some styles, scripts, images and videos. Is there a way to move them to Sharepoint online and have them work the same way they were working as an independent website?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can Use the [modern Script editor web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to embed the ASPX file (as I tested HTML files get downloaded as well), or add the HTML source code directly.

To embed a images and videos to a modern page, see this: [How to Embed a Video to SharePoint Online Modern Pages?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/12/how-to-embed-video-to-sharepoint-online-modern-pages.html)

Comment: Hello Allen, Thank you for the info but in my case the HTML seems to be too big with lot of encrypted data. I tried uploading all the styles and scripts to site assets library and changed the  path in HTML but it does not seem to load at all

Comment: Please provide your steps and styles samples to reproduce this issue on our side.